# django: password change template customization

Tags: python, django, templates, change-password

I want to change password change template in django but I cant. django is seeing the django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/ versions of the templates instead of my beautifully crafted myapp/templates/registration/password*.html

```
urls.py 

from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeDoneView,PasswordChangeView

urlpatterns = [
    path('password_change/',
         PasswordChangeView.as_view(),
         name='password_change'),
    path('password_change/done/',
         PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(),
         name='password_change_done'),

]
```

```
setting.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the template name in the auth view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeDoneView,PasswordChangeView

urlpatterns = [
    path('password_change/',
         PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name="myapp/templates/registration/templatename.html"),
         name='password_change'),
    path('password_change/done/',
         PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name="myapp/templates/registration/templatename.html"),
         name='password_change_done'),

]
```

Source: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.contrib.auth.views/PasswordChangeView/